# Как перемешать массив, не давая элементам сместиться больше чем на заданное значение с их оригинальной позиции?

Tags: алгоритм

Как перемешать массив, не давая элементам сместиться больше чем на заданное значение (N) с их оригинальной позиции? Скажем, для N=1: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` может быть перемешан в `[1, 3, 2, 4, 5]` или `[2, 1, 3, 5, 4]`, но не в `[5, 2, 1, 3, 4]`.

Нет ли случайно какого-нибудь алгоритма? Увы, нагуглить ничего не удаётся, а моя реализация не очень-то равномерная.

Тем не менее, приведу на всякий случай:

```
/// <summary>
/// Возвращает перемешанный заданным образом массив размером size с элементами от 0
/// до size−1. В дальнейшем этот массив будет использован как список новых позиций.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="size">Число элементов</param>
/// <param name="limit">Максимальное смещение</param>
/// <returns>Перемешанный список индексов</returns>
private int[] Shuffle(int size, int limit) {
    var buffer = new int[size];
    for (var i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++) {
        buffer[i] = i;
    }

    for (var i = buffer.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        // Узнаём оригинальную позицию элемента
        var t = buffer[i];

        // Границы для поиска относительно оригинальной позиции
        var a = Math.Max(t - limit, 0);
        var b = Math.Min(t + limit, buffer.Length - 1);

        // Выбираем кандидата на обмен
        var n = _randomInstance.Next(a, b + 1);

        // Самого на себя не меняем
        if (n != i) {
            // Возможные границы обмена для найденного элемента
            var ai = Math.Max(i - limit, 0);
            var bi = Math.Min(i + limit, buffer.Length - 1);

            // Узнаём оригинальную позицию элемента
            var v = buffer[n];

            // Если оригинальная позиция найденного вписывается в границы
            // вокруг i, можно заменить
            if (v >= ai && v <= bi) {
                buffer[i] = buffer[n];
                buffer[n] = t;
            }
        }
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Лично я ничего не понял.:)

Comment: а что по сложность нужно? линейно или большого значения не имеет?

Comment: @pavel да, особого значения не имеет, конечно же. Лишь бы было по возможности равномерно, а так данных совсем немного (но достаточно для того, чтобы вариант «перемешивать не глядя, пока не получится правильно» не подходил). :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Интересно, правильно ли я думаю. Т.к. сложность нас не сильно интересует, то переформулируем задачу, сведя её к максимальному паросочетанию. Ребёр у нас будет порядка N*2*Delta. Сложность как обычно - O(N^3).

В сочетании со случайным перемешиванием через обычный  random_shuffle это даёт все возможные комбинации и более-менее равномерно (для малых N/Delta проверял).

Выкладываю код полностью, с простейшей проверкой на равномерность генерации.

Интересны мнения по поводу корректности данной наркомании :)

```
map<int,int> counter;

void operator delete (void *A){};
void operator delete[] (void *A){};


int n, k;
vector < vector<int> > g;
vector<int> mt;
vector<char> used;

bool try_kuhn (int v) {
    if (used[v])  return false;
    used[v] = true;
    for (size_t i=0; i<g[v].size(); ++i) {
        int to = g[v][i];
        if (mt[to] == -1 || try_kuhn (mt[to])) {
            mt[to] = v;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


int main()
{
    int X = 6;
    int MAX_DELTA = 2;
    srand(time(0));

    for (int Z=0;Z<5000;Z++){
        vector<int> first;
        vector<int> firstB;

        for (int i=0;i<X;i++)
            firstB.push_back(i);
        first.resize(X);

        int n = X;
        int k = X;
        g.resize(X);
        for (int i=0;i<X;i++)
            for (int j = max(0,i-MAX_DELTA); j <= min(X-1, i + MAX_DELTA); j++)
                g[i].push_back(j);

        for (int i=0;i<X;i++)
            random_shuffle(g[i].begin(),g[i].end());

        mt.assign (k, -1);
        vector<char> used1 (n);
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
            for (size_t j=0; j<g[i].size(); ++j)
                if (mt[g[i][j]] == -1) {
                    mt[g[i][j]] = i;
                    used1[i] = true;
                    break;
                }
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
            if (used1[i])  continue;
            used.assign (n, false);
            try_kuhn (i);
        }

        for (int i=0; i<k; ++i)
            if (mt[i] != -1)
                first[mt[i] ] = firstB[i];

        /*for (int i:first)
            cout << i<<" ";
        cout << endl;*/
        int hashC = 0;
        int pow = 1;
        for (int i=0;i<X;i++)
            hashC+=first[i]*pow ,pow*=X;
        counter[hashC]++;

        for (int i=0; i < X;i++)
            if (first[i] - i < -MAX_DELTA || first[i] - i > MAX_DELTA){
                for (int z:first)
                    cout << z<<" ";
                cout <<"FAIL!"<<endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }
        for (auto i : counter){
            int ii = i.first;
            for (int z=0;z<X;z++){
                cout << ii%X<<" ";
                ii/=X;
            }
            cout << " "<<i.second<<endl;
        }
}
```

Код паросочетания просто скопировал [отсюда](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/kuhn_matching)

Comment: Вот это круто! Пойду теперь разбираться, как это вообще работает. И равномернее, чем моё решение (хотя, как я вижу, всё ещё есть некое отклонение, но меньше). 

Закрывать ли мне вопрос или, может быть, пока подождать, не захочет ли ответить кто-нибудь ещё (не очень знаком со stackoverflow)? :)

Comment: @SurfinBird, тут не принято закрывать свои вопросы. Если есть устраивающий Вас ответ, то просто примите его (кликните на "галку" под оценкой ответа)

Comment: Да, крутое решение. Если ещё и убрать ту оптимизацию поиска максимального паросочетания, почти совсем равномерное. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал все же реализовать уже не раз упоминаемый в других ответах [random_shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) для заданного диапазона (т.е. тасование за время O(n)).

Это не законченное решение, а скорее инструмент для тестирования идеи. Основное изменение по сравнению с Вашим вариантом в том, что если нам не нравится случайная перестановка, а именно, нам кажется, что слишком много чисел остаются на своих местах, то мы пробуем переставить пару чисел еще раз (или несколько раз,  задается параметром).

Тут используются два массива -- `a[]` -- перемешиваемые числа и `p[]` -- вспомогательный массив индексов чисел до перетасовки, которые согласованно меняются. Массив `p` используется для определения, а можно ли это число переместить в задаваемый ГСЧ индекс массива?

Вот программа (gcc/g++ в Linux).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>  // для srandom(getpid()) -- если хотим видеть разные результаты в разных запусках

// меняем 2 числа местами если они не уходят со своих мест слишком далеко
static int dswap (int a[], int p[], int i, int j, int d)
{
  int r = 0;

  printf("try swp %d %d (%d,%d)", i, j, a[i], a[j]); // по сути для отладки
  if (p[i] >= j - d && p[i] <= j + d &&
      p[j] >= i - d && p[j] <= i + d) {
    puts("Y");
    r = 1;
    int t = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = t;
    t = p[i];
    p[i] = p[j];
    p[j] = t;
  } else {
    ;  // это безобразие, чтобы легче было комментировать печать, когда надоест не нее смотреть
    puts(""); 
  }

  return r;
}

static inline int vmin (int n, int l) {
  return n < l ? n : l;
}

// ./a.out [[-]Nnumbers [Length [Nswaps]]]
int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int n = atoi(av[1] ? av[1] : "10"),         // размер перестановки
    l = atoi(av[1] && av[2] ? av[2] : "5"),   // дистанция
    k = atoi(av[1] && av[2] && av[3] ? av[3] : "1"); // количество попыток "улучшить"
  if (k < 1)
    k = 1;
  if (n < 0) { // если первый параметр < 0, то случайная последовательность перестановок
    n = -n;
    srand(getpid());
  }
  if (n < 3)
    n = 3;
  if (l < 1 || l > n - 1)
    l = n / 2;

  printf("shuffle %d lim = %d k = %d\n", n, l, k);

  int i, j,
    a[n], // тасуемые числа
    p[n]; // их исходные индексы
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    a[i] = i + 10, p[i] = i;

  // сам алгоритм
  for (i = n - 1; i; --i)
    for (j = 0; j < k; j++) // попытки "улучшения случайности"
      if (dswap(a, p, i, i - rand() % vmin(i + 1, l * 2), l)) 
        break;
      else if (j + 1 < k)   // исключительно для наглядности исследований
        puts("rep");


  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%d ", a[i]);

  return puts("") == EOF;
}
```

Я позапускал с разным количеством попыток обмена (3-й параметр) и откровенно говоря, не понял, что на самом деле лучше. Пробуйте, может какой-то из вариантов понравится более остальных.

Comment: Увы, но, насколько я вижу, несмотря на попытки, распределение всё равно получается так себе. У меня получается, что чем больше попыток, тем распределение неравномернее (скажем, при дистанции, равной 1, с одной попыткой распределение элемента по возможным позициям ≈31.5%, 37.0% и 31.5%, с 2 уже получается что-то вроде ≈30%, 40%, 30%).

Comment: @SurfinBird, а как Вы это считаете (какой-то стат прогой с матожиданием, дисперсиями, хи-квадратом, какие там еще стат штучки)? Я правда  не помню, как оценивать равномерно ли распределены случайные числа. Здесь, само собой для дистанции 1 чем больше попыток, тем выше вероятность, что мы все же переставим 2 числа (а это уже закономерность, т.е. такое же отклонение от случайности, как если бы мы ничего не мешали)

Comment: не, лишь примитивный цикл в сотню тысяч итераций и подсчёт среднего числа попаданий заданного числа в различные позиции. Признаюсь, не уверен, насколько это корректно.

Подозреваю, что вероятность того, что число останется на своём месте, растёт при увеличении числа попыток, потому что увеличивается шанс, что оно вернётся на своё место при переходе к следующему (в данном случае предыдущему) элементу в массиве.

Comment: Число назад (в позицию где оно уже было) тут никогда не переставляется. Оно может остаться на месте (это разрешенная перестановка числа самого с собой). Количество попыток увеличивает шанс найти число, с которым можно обменять данное в рамках ограничений на дистанцию (в т.ч. попасть на вариант обмена самого с собой). / И заодно уж, чуток другой вопрос -- *а какие перестановки Вам нужны* (кажутся хорошими)? Или что значит *равномерное распределение*? (я, если честно, задумался и осознал, что видимо не очень хорошо понимаю, что Вы имеете в виду)

Comment: Хм, видимо, я что-то упускаю. В этой [слегка модифицированной версии](http://pastebin.com/As7EKbB8), выбрасывающей исключение, если число поставлено туда, откуда оно стартовало, это самое исключение выбрасывается, если только основной цикл (работающий с `i`) не будет перескакивать через элемент. (Массива `p` у меня нет, храню оригинальные индексы сразу в `a`.)

Comment: Наверное я не совсем понял задачу. Вы хотите, чтобы каждое число никогда не оставалось на месте? В классическом тасовании это вроде бы не так.

Comment: нет, это я лишь к тому, что при второй и дальнейших попытках число с большей долей вероятности вернётся на место. Судя по результатам.

Comment: Не знаю. Я позапускал `./a.out -10 1 Nattempts`, правда "вручную", посмотрел и не заметил такой закономерности. Вот 2 серии по 10 запусков с количеством попыток 1,2,3,10,20 и число 17 (у Вас 7) осталось на своем месте 4,5,1,4,3 и во второй серии 3,3,2,1,3 раз.

Comment: Ну да, пожалуй, на глаз отличить 33% от 40% будет непросто. :)